# Flow chart / Tree chart In Angular 8

Tags: angular, charts, visualization

I am trying to draw a chart/virtualization of the following. It is like a tree and flow chart concept mixed together.

When the "add new" button is click, the line suppose to connect between the previous node and the parent node.

Is there a library I can leverage on for Angular 8.
Is there any reference library I can reference too as well?

Thanks

[image: Flow chart/tree chart?]

Comment: [NGX-Graph](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ngx-graph](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/). Very impressive and straightforward. There are other paid libraries like [jsplumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/) and others like it.